# Ruby Dashing Error

Tags: ruby, dashing

I tried to install [this dashing widget](https://gist.github.com/jwalton/6614023) and I get the following error when I run `dashing start`

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/dashing-1.3.1/lib/dashing.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `history' for Sinatra::Application:Class (NoMethodError)
```

So then I removed all aspects of this new widget (its folder in the /widgets directory, its job .rb file and the code in the .erb file).  However this error persists and I am no longer able to even start my dashboard.  This is a big problem for me.  Can someone help me out?

EDIT:

The full error is

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/dashing-1.3.1/lib/dashing.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `history' for Sinatra::Application:Class (NoMethodError)
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/dashing-1.3.1/lib/dashing.rb:25:in `open'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/dashing-1.3.1/lib/dashing.rb:25:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (history.yml): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `block in load_file'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `open'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `load_file'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/dashing-1.3.1/lib/dashing.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from config.ru:2:in `require'
        from config.ru:2:in `block in <main>'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from config.ru:1:in `new'
        from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:182:in `load_rackup_config'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:72:in `start'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:200:in `run_command'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:156:in `run!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/thin:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Check the stack trace, not just this line, and see where it's being called.

Comment: I have included the full error message

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with my psych.rb file

Comment: Maybe there's an error in the YAML file it's trying to parse?

Comment: history.yml is emtpy.  Is this the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if empty is valid YAML, so that could be it.

Comment: Do you have any idea what should be in this history.yml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by renaming the old history file

```
mv history.yml history
```

and then restarting the server. In my case thats

```
rackup -p 3030 -s puma
```

The history.yml file didn't reappear until after I stopped the server. I checked it with nano and it was full of data.
Sorry I can't shed any light as to why it may have happened.
Server details. Ubuntu 13.10 32bit Desktop

Comment: I discovered today that one possible cause for problems with history.yml is closing an SSH connection while Dashing is running (Windows bluescreened on me so it wasn't my fault!).
To avoid this start with the Daemon switch
'rackup -p 3030 -s puma -D'
as this returns to the prompt after puma has started. 
Not so useful when you're testing jobs but it does explain the problem